# Which statement is right for capacitor in steady state?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

what should should I say for  a capacitor in steady state

*is the potential drop in capacitor 0 due to no current  the current in capacitor 0 due to no potential drop or?*

[image]

For the former statement I get circuit a and for later circuit b

Comment: [Check this pdf](https://old.amu.ac.in/emp/studym/99994220.pdf).  , when capactir is charged up it acts as open circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *steady state* here does not refer to the capacitor, but to the whole circuit. There is a current flowing through the resistances, which is why it is a *steady* rather than *equilibrium* state. (*Steady state* generally means that nothing changes with time, i.e., there is no charging/discharging, etc.)